# find the difference between two sets of pointers to the same object

Tags: c++, pointers, set

How can i find the difference between two sets of pointers to the same object?

Is there an efficient way without iterating through all the objects of both sets.

i have two of these sets:

```
std::set<Object*>
```

If an object private member(name) is the same as the other objects name that means that the object is the same.

Comment: A `set` of pointers sounds like a mistake.

Comment: How do you define this difference?

Comment: Have a look at [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference).

Comment: unless you do something special, a set of pointers to the same object will only have one element. So it isn't clear what you are asking here.

Comment: If the "same" objects are replicated in several collections, then why do you need pointers?

Comment: @Pubby, there are plenty of good uses for a set of pointers. You can work with objects in a set without the cost or complication of copying each time. Look at the Boost ptr container libraries.

Answer (score 0):

STL's algorithm library is awesome, extensible, and underused.

This will give you the set difference as a vector (I suppose you could convert that to a set, but there's no need, at least for what you asked, and a vector is faster since the sets are already sorted).

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> set_diff(std::set<T> const &a, std::set<T> const &b) {
    std::vector v<T>;
    std::set_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), v.begin());
    return v;
}
```

Optionally, put after the constructor

```
    v.reserve(a.size() + b.size());
```

and before the return (C++11)

```
    v.shrink_to_fit();
```

**Note**: This yields the items in `a` that are not in `b`. To find all items in one of the two but not the other, use `std::set_symmetric_difference` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean different is finding pointer elements which only appear in one set. The most efficient way is to iterate the two sets synchronously and this will cost only O(n+m) time, in which n, m denote the size of two sets, which in general case is the lower bound for the problem.

Luckily, STL container set use balanced binary search tree as its base, we can iterate all the elements in order in linear time, so O(n+m) can be achieved.

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> set_diff(std::set<T> const &a, std::set<T> const &b) {
  std::vector<T> v;
  auto ita = a.begin();
  auto itb = b.begin();
  while (ita != a.end() && itb != b.end()) {
    if (*ita == *itb) {
      ++ita, ++itb;
    } else if (*ita < *itb) {
      v.push_back(*ita);
      ++ita;
    } else {
      v.push_back(*itb);
      ++itb;
    }
  }
  for (; ita != a.end(); v.push_back(*ita), ++ita);
  for (; itb != b.end(); v.push_back(*itb), ++itb);
  return v;
}
```